# jQuery $.loadImage is not a function How to resolve it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery:

```
$.loadImage($(".Barcode_image_" + $(sel).val())).done(function() {
    var img = $(".Barcode_image_" + $(sel).val());
    alert(img.prop("naturalWidth"));
})
```

Anyone can please tell why it displaying error

> Uncaught TypeError: $.loadImage is not a function

How can I resolve it?

Comment: `.loadImage()` is not part of jQuery -> you're missing a library

Comment: Which library needs to add to using this function?

Comment: google/yahoo/bing/... -> jquery image loader

Comment: Actually this function is not available in jQuery library. How you come to know this is valid function? provide link of this function document.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to wait for a image to load for further processing then you can use `.promise()` in jquery.

```
  $.when( $(".Barcode_image_" + $(sel).val()) ).done(function() {
    var img = $(".Barcode_image_" + $(sel).val());
    alert(img.prop("naturalWidth"));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For image preloading you can try out this...so that once the image is loaded, you can access the properties

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    $.preloadImages("/*Image Path*/");
});

$.preloadImages = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    $("<img />").load( function(){
        jQuery("body").addClass("image Loaded");
    }).attr("src", arguments[i]).appendTo('body').css('display','none');
  }
}
```

here what we are doing is preloading the image and appending to body.So that once the image is loaded, it will add the "image Loaded" class to body.

Thanks !